# Angular - Reactive Forms - FormGroupName inside FormGroupName

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have a nested JSON response coming back from an API and is structured differently then how I need to display it on the template, for example:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'reactive-form-example',
  styles: ['./reactive-form-example.component.css'],
  template: `
    <form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
        <div formGroupName="first">
            <input type="text" placeholder="some id" formControlName="someId">
            <div formGroupName="second">
                <input type="text" placeholder="some text" formControlName="someText">
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
  `
})
export class ReactiveFormExampleComponent {
    form = new FormGroup({
        first: new FormGroup({
            someId: new FormControl('587824')
        }),
        second: new FormGroup({
            someText: new FormControl('the sky is blue')
        })
    });
    onSubmit(value) {
        console.log('Submit', this.form.value);
    }
}
```

**Question:** Is it possible to have a `formGroupName` nested within another `formGroupName`, or is there a better way to achieve this same result using reactive forms?

Comment: can you try `[formGroup]="form.get('first')"` instead of `formGroupName="first"`

Comment: @emostafa that works! is this good practice?

Comment: to be honest, I am not sure, but i think it is, in the angular docs under nested form groups, you will find a section about it.

https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#more-formcontrols

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes. `formGroupName` can be nested within another `formGroupName`.

`formGroupName` and `formControlName` attributes work by finding a control with that particular name within the parent `FormGroup`.

Note that your problem is caused because you're trying to find a `FormGroup` named `second` within the `first` FormGroup:

```html
<form [formGroup]="form">
    <div formGroupName="first">
        <div formGroupName="second">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

To make that work, you'd have to adapt your model as follows, where `second` becomes a child of `first`:

```js
form = new FormGroup({
    first: new FormGroup({
        someId: new FormControl('587824'),
        second: new FormGroup({
            someText: new FormControl('the sky is blue')
        })
    }),        
});
```

The reason why the suggestion of emostafa works, is because you ask the `form` instance to get a direct child named `second` within the model. Which does exist in this case.

Comment: Yeah I'm aware of this, however the JSON response format is out of my control so I was looking for a solution of dynamically creating the structure and being able to use within the template however I need. So for instance basically recursively traversing the JSON response creating a `FormGroup` at every nested level, but the problem is that then the template is jailed if your trying to bind to the other nested group.

Comment: @JordanDavis I'd suggest asking another question which focusses on this. Giving one or two examples of JSON formats that come back and asking how to best handle those within reactive forms.

Some rubber ducky questions: Do you care about having the JSON structure represented in the HTML? Isn't it possible to just iterate across all the questions in a flat way in the HTML? Is [this](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-form) useful?